# Helm modify a multiline string line by line

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a function which returns a multiline string. This function is called at severale places - so I don't want to modify it.However at one place I need to prefix each line with a character.

```
{{- define "myfunc" -}}
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
{{- end -}}
```

At one place in my templates I need to bind these to a list as elements with prefix "-"

**expected result:**

```
args:
  - aaa
  - bbb
  - ccc
  - ddd
```

**My attempt 1:**

```
   args:
     - {{- include "myfunc" . | nindent 8 }}
```

result:

```
 args:
  - 
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
  ddd
```

**My attempt 2:**

```
  iterating over it, something like
   args:
     {{- range include "myfunc" . }}
     - {{ . }}
     {{- end }}
```

result:

```
Error: template : .... range can't iterate over aaa
   bbb
   ccc
   ddd
```

**My actual solution:** 
Just copy the existing function with a bit of modification

```
{{- define "myfunc2" -}}
- aaa
- bbb
- ccc
- ddd
{{- end -}}
```

The question is how to bind the original function's result to args? How to apply a modification to each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to treat it as a set of string data, and then process it in the same way as a string

_helper.yaml

```yaml
{{- define "myfunc" -}}
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
{{- end -}}
```

template/xxx.yaml

```yaml
args: 
{{- $data := include "myfunc" . }}
{{- range ( split "\n" $data) }}
  - {{ . }}
{{- end }}
```

output:

```yaml
args: 
  - aaa
  - bbb
  - ccc
  - ddd
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! (By the end I always forget it is basically...'go' :) )